# numpy.savetxt saves array in a single cell?

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I have a numpy array `list_of_vars`. I want to save each element of the array in a new cell, in a row, in a .csv file. This is an example of a few of the elements in `list_of_vars`:
[image]

Ideally, each element (`ADC_ALT_TC`, `ADC_AOA_TC`, etc.) should be in a new cell in Excel, spaced horizontally in a row. However, using this code puts them all into one cell separated by a space:

```
with open(fname, 'w') as f:     
    np.savetxt(f, list_of_vars, fmt = '%s', delimiter = ',', newline = ' ')
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `newline = '\n'` or `newline = ''` or just miss out the `newline` parameter altogether.

Comment: Could you demonstrate with a small array, and show the actual `csv` file.  There's some ambiguity in your description.

Answer (score 0):

Not really leveraging numpy's vectorization here, but I don't think the internal method is any faster. This code will do what you wish to do.

```
with open("file_to_write_to.txt", mode="w") as f:
  for i in arr_of_str:
    f.write(i + ",")`
```

EDIT: I think all you needed was "," as your newline character for your code to function.

```
np.savetxt("test", arr, fmt = '%s', delimiter = ',', newline = ',')
```

Comment: `savetxt` is pure python, just iterating on 'rows' and doing a formatted write.  So you are right, it's not going to be any faster.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is a 1d array of strings, a straightforward use of `savetxt` puts one string per line:

```
In [164]: arr = np.array(['one','two','three'])
In [165]: np.savetxt('test.txt', arr, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
In [166]: cat test.txt
one
two
three
```

Your newline approach:

```
In [172]: np.savetxt('test.txt', [arr], delimiter=',', fmt='%s', newline=' ')
In [173]: cat test.txt
one,two,three In [174]:
```

If instead the array is 2d, such as (1,3), all strings are on one line:

```
In [169]: np.array([arr])
Out[169]: array([['one', 'two', 'three']], dtype='<U5')
In [170]: np.savetxt('test.txt', [arr], delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
In [171]: cat test.txt
one,two,three
```